# How to do a CEF window refresh?

Tags: html, chromium, chromium-embedded, chromium-tabs

I have an app with 2 tabs. The container of app is developed in Native code and CEF has been used to open html pages in one of the tabs. When I switch from Tab 1 (Native) to Tab 2(CEF) contents of Tab 1 are visible on Tab 2, though Tab 2 has html page loaded. As I hover mouse over Tab 2 in this situation or do any activity on Tab 2(which has presently content of Tab 1 visible), html content becomes visible. I have checked that I hide/show calls are properly being sent.

As I am not able to find any solution I would like to know if there is some way to refresh the CEF page. I think if I am able to refresh Tab 2 at every switch to Tab 2 it should work fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In C# you can use this method:

```
chromeBrowser.Reload(true);
```

Test on VS 2015

Read more in document: [WebBrowserExtensions.Reload Method](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Reload_1.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what platform/language you are using. The following C++ code will reload the web page.

```
CefRefPtr<ClientHandler> g_handler;
g_handler->GetBrowser()->Reload();
```

You could find cefclient project from the official package, It demonstrates various CEF API usage.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET I use the following code:

`Call webBrowser.GetBrowser.Reload()`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code but it **does not worked:**

```
browser.Refresh();
```

and this code **worked** for me:

```
browser.Reload(true);
```

(I'm using Cefsharp in C# Windows Form)